# Perl regex positive lookbehind to search through newline and space

Tags: regex, bash, perl, zsh

I'm trying to automate updating of my `~/.ssh/config file`. When I do an online regex tester it works as I want to with PCRE2 (so perl 5.30.3 compatible) at [regex101](https://regex101.com), but when I try to replicate on my local machine, it fails.

The command uses a positive lookbehind to read-through a word, a line break, four spaces, a word, a space, and then aims to replace from that point onward until the end of the line:

`cat ~/.ssh/config | perl -pe 's/(?<=c9\n\s{4}Hostname )ec2.+/TEST/g'`.

My ~/.ssh/config file looks like this (example only, changed for security):

```
Host c9
    Hostname ec2-xxx.compute.amazonaws.com
    User ec2-user
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa2
```

With the above regex, I would expect the output to look like this:

```
Host c9
    Hostname TEST
    User ec2-user
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa2
```

It works on the test-site, but when I run locally it works right up until the point where I add any spaces after the line break. So,

```
cat ~/.ssh/config | perl -pe 's/(?<=c9\n)/TEST/g'
```

gives

```
Host c9
TEST    Hostname ec2-xxx.compute.amazonaws.com
    User ec2-user
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa2
```

But the following just gives back the unchanged input.

```
cat ~/.ssh/config | perl -pe 's/(?<=c9\n )/TEST/g'
```

I've tested in bash and zsh, and I'm running perl 5, version 30, subversion 3 (v5.30.3). Thanks for any help.
[1](https://regex101.com): https://regex101.com

Comment: Re "*to read-through a word, a line break*", But you use `-p`, which executes the program against each line of the input. Add `-0777` to tell Perl to treat the entire file as one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/c9(?=\n\s{4})/TEST/g' ~/.ssh/config
```

Comment: This doesn't do what  if OP asks because it replaces every line after `Host c9`, not just `Hostname` and not just hostnames that start with `ec2`

Answer (score 1):

Use `sed` to find `Host c9` (via `/^Host c9$/`), then on the next line (via `n` command), replace the hostname (via `s/Hostname ec2.*/Homename TEST/`):

```
sed '/^Host c9$/{n; s/Hostname ec2.*/Homename TEST/;}' ~/.ssh/config
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/qVpBSa).